# Python: write data to specific cell

Tags: python, csv

I need some data and I need write it to one column but to different string

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
list1 = ['111', '333', '555', '777', '8888']
list2 = [1, 5, 56, 44, 2]
with open('hh1.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for (elem1, elem2) in zip(list1, list2):
        writer.writerow([elem1])
```

I want to write `elem1` to cell with number `elem2`, i mean
`111` in `A1`, `333` in `A5` etc.
How can I do that?

Comment: what do you want to write in the in-between rows?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it will be empty, but I need to write it in loop and numbers may be not in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So initialize your list with empty values according to `list2` max index. Then, fill it according to `list1,list2` indexes/values tuples using `zip` as you did in your attempt.

```
list1 = ['111', '333', '555', '777', '8888']
list2 = [1, 5, 56, 44, 2]
rows_to_write = [[""] for _ in range(max(list2))]
for i,v in zip(list2,list1):
    rows_to_write[i-1][0] = v
```

At this point `rows_to_write` is worth:

```
[['111'], ['8888'], [''], [''], ['333'], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], ['777'], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], [''], ['555']]
```

then write the rows in 1 instruction (don't append)

```
with open('hh1.csv', 'w',newline='') as f: # python 3
    csv.writer(f).writerows(rows_to_write)
```

This creates a single-row "sparse" csv file. (`open('hh1.csv', 'wb') as f` for python 2)

Comment: It write `111` to cell `1, 113, 225`

Comment: it's not even possible. Those values are not in `list2` range... oh, you have to use `w` mode not `a` !! rewrite the file from zero.

Comment: Can you say, but if I don't have a list with numbers, but get it in loop, can i write like this in loop?

Comment: I try to do that, but it don't write that

Comment: probably a newline issue. Check my edit on `open` of the .csv file

Comment: I use python2, I have created `list = range(0, 100)` and  `rows_to_write = [[""] for _ in range(max(list))]` but real elements, what number of cell I should write I get in loop and next `rows_to_write[num - 1][0] = email
        csv.writer(f).writerows(rows_to_write)` but it writes not to cell like `num`